# asp.net 4.0 caching issue

Tags: asp.net, caching, webchartcontrol

Need help resolving a problem related to ASP.NET application data caching and chart control.  I have a simple test page containg the chart control.  Since the chart uses data from the database, I have created a custom object called chartData that contains all data needed by the chart.  When I create the chartData from scratch (because it's not in cache), the chart renders correctly.  When I retrieve the chartData from the cache, I get the exception below.  I inspected the object returned from the cache in the debugger, and it appears correct.  Any suggestions on what's going on here?

This is happening on my development system (Win 7, VS 2010, C#).

As it seems to be relate to the chart datasource, here is the line of my code that affect the datasource property:

```
myChart.DataSource = myChartData.DataSource;
```

myChartData.DataSource is a List of myChartDataPoint
where myChartDataPoint is

```
    public class myChartDataPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }
    public int Y3 { get; set; }
}
```

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImage.DataBind(IEnumerable dataSource, ArrayList seriesList) +451
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly) +400
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImage.GetImage(Single resolution) +1035
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.SaveImage(Stream imageStream) +124
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +375
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +173
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +31
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3060

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

```
    /// <summary>
/// Spline Chart Data
/// </summary>
public class ChartData
{
    private SeriesList _seriesList = new SeriesList();
    private ChartDataPoint3YList _dataSource = new ChartDataPoint3YList();
    private StringList _legendTextList = new StringList();
    private StringList _axisXLabelList = new StringList();

    /// <summary>
    /// Chart Title
    /// </summary>
    public string ChartTitle { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// X axis title
    /// </summary>
    public string AxisXTitle { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Y axis title
    /// </summary>
    public string AxisYTitle { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// X Axis point label strings.
    /// </summary>
    public StringList AxisXLabelList
    {
        get { return _axisXLabelList; }
        set { _axisXLabelList = value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Legend strings.
    /// </summary>
    public StringList LegendTextList
    {
        get { return _legendTextList; }
        set { _legendTextList = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Datasource to be used by the chart, contains data for all chart data points
    /// </summary>
    public ChartDataPoint3YList DataSource
    {
        get { return _dataSource; }
        set { _dataSource = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Chart series collection
    /// </summary>
    public SeriesList SeriesList
    {
        get { return _seriesList; }
        set { _seriesList = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Chart data specific to one chart series
    /// </summary>
    public class ChartSeriesData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Legend text for the series
        /// </summary>
        public string Legend { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data Points of the series
        /// </summary>
        public ChartDataPoint3YList DataPoints { get; set; }
    }
}

    public class ChartDataPoint3YList : List<ChartDataPoint3Y> { }

    public class ChartDataPoint3Y
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }
    public int Y3 { get; set; }
}
```

---

I got this to work.  Perhaps someone could tell me why this fixed it because I don’t know.  The exception went away after I replaced

```
foreach (Series series in chartData.SeriesList) myChart.Series.Add(series);
```

with

```
foreach (Series series in chartData.SeriesList)   
{
   SeriesItem newItem = new Series();
        newItem … set the item properties using the relevant values from series
    …
    myChart.Series.Add(newItem);
 }
```

The obvious difference is that the chart object no longer references cached chartData.SeriesList.  Have no idea why that made a difference.

Comment: Can you show the code for myChartData? I'm guessing something is wrong with the caching.

Comment: I have added the code to the end of the original post.